# Loading from mainBundle

Tags: ios, swift

In a some popular open source swift project. I noticed following approach used to load a file from main bundle.

```
@objc class TestClass: NSObject { }

let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: TestClass.self)
let path = bundle.pathForResource(filename, ofType: "json")
```

We can also use this approach.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "json")
```

Why would someone choose first approach over second one?

Comment: if you have different bundles in your project (like library or framework) you could be sure to load the right content from external bundle explicitly, if you use the first approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns the bundle that contains the `TestClass` class:

```
NSBundle(forClass: TestClass.self)
```

While this returns the main bundle of the application:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle()
```

If you execute this code from your application code, it will always return your main bundle. But if that class is contained in a different library or framework, it will return the bundle that contains it.

For example, all Swift libraries in CocoaPods are integrated using dynamic frameworks, and they are deployed in a different bundle inside the main bundle. So all the frameworks must use the embedded bundle to access their resources.

I'd recommend using the first approach (`NSBundle(forClass:)` method) to improve code portability. And it's required when creating dynamic frameworks.